# How to select radio button using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to click this radio button using selenium and python.

```
<input type="radio" name="tweet_target_1" value="website" class="tweet-website-button radio-selection-validate serialize-me newline-before field-order-15">
```

I have

```
website = driver.find_element(name="tweet_target_1")
website.click()
```

but it's not allowing me to click it.  How can I click using a combo of name, value or class, value etc.?

Is there a good source of info about how to use selenium? Because most of what I've found is on java and I'm using python.

**EDIT: using XPATH**

I tried

```
website = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//form[@id='dmca_form' and @class='twitter-form custom-form']/div[20][@class='list-container']/div[1][@class='list-item']/div[7][@class='clearfix inf-tweet init-hide']/div[@class='input']/ul[@class='options']/li[2]/label/input[@class='tweet-website-button radio-selection-validate serialize-me newline-before field-order-15']/")
website.click()
```

I keep getting

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you found the documentation that said you could call `find_element` like that, but you should either be doing `driver.find_element_by_name("tweet_target_1")` or `driver.find_element(By.NAME, "tweet_target_1")` (having first imported `By` of course).  Also, Selenium Java code is pretty easily convertible to Python code; it follows a few pretty simple transformation rules, and if you still have questions, all the code for the library itself will also be on your machine to look at.

Comment: maybe I am using a different version of selenium but it doesnt work for me i keep getting `website = driver.find_element(By.NAME,"tweet_target_1")
NameError: name 'By' is not defined`. ALSO i need to be able to find a element by BOTH name/id and value.

Comment: Did you `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By` first?  And yeah, that's why there is `find_element_by_name` and `find_element_by_id`, as well as both `By.NAME` and `By.ID`.  `By.ID` is actually the default for `find_element` too...

Comment: ok you were right. but is there no option for value? As you can see the above is a radio button that has only name and value. I cant select name because there are more than one option and I can't do class cause it shows up other places. Is it not an option to select by name then click by value?

Comment: You have to select the element by something, but you can use a xpath or css locator, both of which allow you to index by arbitrary attribute.

Comment: You used `find_elements`.  If you want to find a single element, then use `find_element`.  `find_elements` will get you a list of elements matching the xpath, which you then have to iterate over or select from yourself, separately.  Do you have much programming (and specifically Python programming) experience?  Selenium is fairly simple to use, but it's still programming, and you still need to know the basics of data structures and functions.

Comment: thanks!! clearly im new to this. Selenium is pretty simple. its difficult when there are so many different docs saying different things. just on more thing. is it possible to run this in the background? for example when i run my script it opens firefox and fills the fields. could i have all that run in the background so i dont see it?

Comment: You could run it in a VM or maybe against a virtual display, but that's going to take some nontrivial and fairly advanced configuration and engineering.  You also could run it with one of the headless drivers like HTMLUnit, but then you aren't really doing browser testing.  So the short answer is "no".

Answer (score 2):

I know this comes a little too late perhaps, but I joined just recently.

Tip: Use, Firebug and with it Firepath. Locate the radio button and find out the xpath for the element in question.

```
website = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//**")
website.click()
```

OR

```
website = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//**").click()
```

This should work all the time you try. Also, just using `from selenium import webdriver`
should make the `click()` function work correctly.

Comment: Hi @grizzlyBearGrouser, one small tip you may want to format your code examples, for code blocks indent four spaces, and for inline code using backticks (e.g. `code`)

Comment: @robjohncox: Hey, thanks for the tip. Will keep it in mind from here on.